Prevent Independent Dependency Workflow from Running When Both Shared and Dependency Projects Change in GitHub Actions
I'm managing a GitHub repository with two separate projects:

shared-project01/ dependency-project01/

I have set up two GitHub Actions workflows:
1. Dependency-Build1 (dependency-build1.yml):
Triggers:
workflow_call: Allows this workflow to be invoked by other workflows.
push: Triggers on changes to dependency-project01/** on the master branch.
Behavior:
Runs independently when only dependency-project01/** changes.
Should skip running independently when invoked via workflow_call from the shared workflow.
2. Shared-Build01 (shared-build01.yml):
Triggers:
push: Triggers on changes to shared-project01/** on the master branch.
Behavior:
Builds the shared project.
Calls Dependency-Build1 and Dependency-Build2 via workflow_call
Current Workflow Files:
Dependency-build.yaml
name: Dependency-Build1

on:   
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      called_via_workflow_call:
        type: boolean
        default: false  # Default value if not triggered by workflow_call   push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:   
  check-changes:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      dependency_changed: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.dependency }}
   steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Filter changes
        id: changes
        uses: dorny/paths-filter@v3
        with:
          filters: |
            dependency:
              - 'dependency-project01/**'

      # Debugging the output of the change detection
      - name: Debug Changes Output
        run: |
          echo "Changes Output: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.dependency }}"

  dependency-build:
    needs: check-changes
    if: needs.check-changes.outputs.dependency_changed == true && inputs.called_via_workflow_call == 'false'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Debug Job Start
        run: |
          echo "Dependency-build job started"

      # Debugging the values of outputs and inputs
      - name: Output Dependency Changed
        run: |
          echo "Dependency Changed: ${{ needs.check-changes.outputs.dependency_changed }}"

      - name: Debug Workflow Call Input
        run: |
          echo "Called via Workflow: ${{ inputs.called_via_workflow_call }}"

      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Build Dependency Project
        run: |
          echo "Building Dependency Project..."

Shared-Build01 Workflow
    name: Shared-Build01

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'shared-project01/**'
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  complete-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Say Hello
        run: echo "The Shared-Build01 job has been completed successfully!"
      - name: Sleep for 30 seconds
        run: sleep 30s
        shell: bash

  call_dependency_build1:
    needs: complete-job
    uses: ./.github/workflows/dependency-build1.yml
    with:
      called_via_workflow_call: true

The Issue:
When I push changes to both shared-project01/ and dependency-project01/, the following happens:
Both Workflows Trigger:
The independent Dependency-Build1 workflow runs due to changes in dependency-project01/.
The shared Shared-Build01 workflow runs and calls Dependency-Build1 via workflow_call.
Unexpected Behavior:
The independent Dependency-Build1 workflow still runs, causing the dependency project to be built twice:
Independently due to the push to dependency-project01/**.
As part of the shared build via workflow_call.
Desired Behavior:
When both projects have changes:
Do not run the independent Dependency-Build1 workflow.
Only run the dependency build as part of the shared workflow via workflow_call.
When only dependency-project01/ changes:
Run the independent Dependency-Build1 workflow.
When only shared-project01/ changes:
Run the shared workflow and call the dependency build via workflow_call.
What I've Tried:
Using paths, paths-ignore in on.push to specify project folders.
Adding if conditions to skip builds based on input flags.
Utilizing actions like dorny/paths-filter@v3 to detect change.
Question: How can I configure my GitHub Actions workflows to prevent the independent Dependency-Build1 workflow from running when both shared-project01/ and dependency-project01/ have changes, ensuring that the dependency build runs only as part of the Shared-Build01 workflow via workflow_call? I want to maintain separate workflow files without mixing project paths in their triggers.
Any guidance or example configurations to achieve this behavior would be greatly appreciated!
